# Aligning different bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a form as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99cg4aws/).
**`CSS`** is:

```
#mainContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.form {
    padding-left: 0%;
    height: 123px;
    min-height: 520px;
    min-width: 350px;
    width: 34%;
    background: #166bb3;
}
#formDiv {
    margin: 5%;
}
#username, #selectCou {
    width: -moz-available;
    height: 36px;
}
#dob {
    height: 36px;
}
#selectGen {
    height: 36px;
    width: 149px;
}
```

You can see that `Or` is coming below the form. I want it to appear beside `Fill your information here`. How can I do it?
For more clarity, here is the screen shot:
[image: img]

Comment: can't reach .... what you are saying ..can you say it again ?

Comment: Check the edited question

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Fill your information here</h4>

    //put your form here

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Or</h4>

    //your Or content here

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bootstrap columns you should stick to the implemented Grid system classes (you can find the doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) ).
This grid system splits a row into 12 hypotetical columns that you can enlarge as you want, bearing in mind that the maximum width is 12. You can have 12 columns with width 1/12 or 2 columns with width 6/12 or any combination of columns which total width must be 12/12.

To achieve what you want you should wrap 2 6-col divs in a row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Left form
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Right form
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```